# Probability of at least two occurring?

Tags: python, probability

I have a list of probabilities, each probability represents the probability of success. I want to get the probability of 2 or more people success. I know it's calculated by 1-P(all fail)-P(one success), how can I get P(one success)?

```
import numpy  
success = [0.1,0.2,0.3,....]

fail= [(1-i) for i in success]

P_all_fail = numpy.prod(fail)
```

Answer (score 0):

The probability, that event i is success and all other fails, is

```
P_all_fail *success[i] /fail[i]
```

and so, the probability, that exactly one is success and all other fails, is

```
P_one_success = P_all_fail * numpy.sum([ s / f for s,f in zip(success,fail)])
```

Answer (score 0):

The probability of **exactly one success** can be calculated by adding the probabilities of each person being the only successor. Since this individual probability is the probability of the person successing times the probability of everyone else failing, the code should be:

```py
P_one_success = 0
current_P = 1
for x in success:
    current_P = x
    #we start by getting the probability of success for our current person
    for y in success:
        if y != x:
            current_P = current_P * (1 - y)
            #here we multiply our chance of having exactly one success by the chance that 
            #every other person fails
    P_one_success = P_one_success + current_P
    #finally we add all of these probabilities together
```